# Write perl script to copy file names with .ext extension to a list

Tags: cygwin

I need to search all the files in directory `C:\vehicles`. I want to open every file and copy the whole row that contains any of the words: `make`, `model` or `year`.

This is what I have but it's not working. I'm still new to all this.

`$ grep -rE pattern"(make|model|year)" cygdrive/c/vehicles/`

Much help appreciated as I'll have to do everything by hand if I don't figure it out tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
grep -rE "make\|model\|year" /Directory/To/Search/ > /Path/To/file_to_save_in.txt
```

The > will direct the output (i.e. matching lines) to the specified file. Or if you want to test it first and just direct the output to the command line:

```
grep -rE "make\|model\|year" /Directory/To/Search/
```

Comment: so if the directory is c:\vehicles and the file I want to write to is vehicles.txt located in c:\log then I would input:                   grep -rE "make|model|year" /cygdrive/c/vehicles > /cygdrive/c/vehicles.txt

Comment: I'm not too familiar with cygwin but you're throwing that into what appears to be c:\vehicles.txt. If you want to throw it in c:\log\vehicles.txt, try:

grep -rE "make|model|year" /cygdrive/c/vehicles/ > /cygdrive/c/log/vehicles.txt

Also, try:

grep -rE "make|model|year" /cygdrive/c/vehicles/

to make sure you're actually getting matches

Comment: It didn't work for me. Is there a similiar alternative in perl maybe?

Comment: Cd into the vehicles directory and try this: grep -rE "make|model|year" . (include the dot)

Comment: Can you grep anything from a single file?

Comment: Also, try escaping the pipes: `grep -rE "make\|model\|year" /cygdrive/c/vehicles/` or try `grep -e make -e model -e year /cygdrive/c/vehicles/` Sorry I can't be more of help, I don't have a Win/CygWin instance going.